# Vertically centering text within circles created with border-radius

Tags: css, transform, vertical-alignment, centering

Today I was having an awful lot of trouble getting some small text vertically centered within elements that were circle which were created using `border-radius`.

Some of the elements looked fine, but one in particular (a lowercase *e* was too close to the bottom); I had `2px` of `padding` and it seemed to look fine; however once viewed on a mobile device it was slightly lower.

Here is some code that is as close of a replica as I could come up with to show the issue; you will notice this text has a similar issue with the lowercase *e* being too close to the bottom.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="option">
    <span class="icon">t</span>
    <span class="text">123456789</span>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <span class="icon">f</span>
    <span class="text">123456789</span>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <span class="icon">e</span>
    <span class="text"><a href="mailto:moo@moo.com">moo@moo.com</a></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.option {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.option .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.option .text {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7bygsgn1/7/

Whilst I haven't tried them with the particular code on jsfiddle, when I was having the issue today I tried a whole range of centering techniques including:

- Using `line-height`
- Using `absolute` positioning
- Using `vertical-align: middle;` in conjunction with `display: table-cell;`
- Negative Margins
- Using the method explained [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

Either it had no affect on the centering or caused the shape of the circle to change.

Is there any way you can reliably vertically center in situations such as this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an inline-block  pseudo-element with an height of 24px / 100% , and vertical-align it to middle.

```css
.option {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.option .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

/* here the pseudo-element method */
.option .icon:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 100%;/* cause here we have a square and width for percentage vertical (padding/margin) is the reference , height:100%; or height:24px; will do as well */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* end update */
.option .text {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="option">
  <span class="icon">t</span>
  <span class="text">123456789</span>
</div>
<div class="option">
  <span class="icon">f</span>
  <span class="text">123456789</span>
</div>
<div class="option">
  <span class="icon">e</span>
  <span class="text"><a href="mailto:moo@moo.com">moo@moo.com</a></span>
</div>
```

or display:flex; , the most simple:

```css
.option {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.option .icon {
  /* next-three lines to center content both axis */
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.option .text {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="option">
  <span class="icon">t</span>
  <span class="text">123456789</span>
</div>
<div class="option">
  <span class="icon">f</span>
  <span class="text">123456789</span>
</div>
<div class="option">
  <span class="icon">e</span>
  <span class="text"><a href="mailto:moo@moo.com">moo@moo.com</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I ran the snippet in your first suggestion and it looks good; however when I added it to a fork of my fiddle the *e* still sits too low - did I miss something? http://jsfiddle.net/mn77cz9r/1/ - As for flex, I need to support IE9 - does that have any graceful fallback?

Comment: @Brett, you forgot to remove the line-height propertie wich is no longer needed and messes around :) http://jsfiddle.net/7bygsgn1/11/

Comment: Ahh, thanks! :) Can I ask how this works though? How does adding an empty element before the icon element fix the alignment?

Comment: @Brett, it is empty but has the full height of its container. displayed as inline-block, it will stand by defaut on the baseline alike an img or an input. then, vertical-align sets its position among text or other inline-block element.

Answer (score 1):

Vertically/Horizontally center anything inside a parent element without knowing the heights/widths of either:

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.parent {
  text-align: center;

  /* May want to do this if there is risk the container may be narrower than the element inside */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.parent:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Essentially this creates a ghost element inside the parent that allows the child to be positioned relative to it. The height: 100% allows the vertical-align: middle to do its job properly.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Credit to https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/